# Using a Loader to submit data

Tags: android

I'm wondering if an Android [`Loader`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) (more specifically [`AsyncTaskLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html)) is the correct job for asynchronously submitting data to a web service.

The way I see it, most of the examples deal with grabbing data and displaying it to a user. For such operations things like having it "accidentally" hit the URL endpoint twice, or caching data is the norm.

However, when we're dealing with submitting data we want a way to absolutely make sure that:

- the data is only submitted once
- the submit operation is done anew each time we call it
- we can pass a result back that will notify the user that the action was successful (or failed)

So, with that being said, how would I go about using the Loader pattern to send data in an asynchronous fashion? Are there any examples that exist for this type of use-case? Or is a Loader not the right thing, and I should be using something else altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `AsyncTask`. The loader caches data internally and returns it to the app to be displayed by the app, it is not really designed to submit data. Why do you think you need to use a `Loader` for this?

Comment: Well I need it to not run on the UI thread. But like I said in the question, if there's something else to use for this please suggest it.

Comment: Asynctask by default does not survive orientation changes so that's why I'd rather use the loader version of it.

Comment: It it very easy to have it persist, certainly much easier than trying to hack a loader. Just use `getLastNonConfigurationInstance` or a retained fragment if you are using fragments already: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getLastNonConfigurationInstance()

Answer (score 4):

I don't agree with Nikolay on this one (I know how it sounds with my reputation against his;)). I use Loader (`AsyncTaskLoader`) to write data as well. More specifically I have an `AsyncTaskLoader` which checks for data on-line and then writes it to local database. It works like a charm and doesn't have AsyncTask drawbacks when it comes to persistence and leaking problems.

And it has the thing which you need (probably needed) - it doesn't run twice e.g. on configuration change, because it reconnects to the existing loader.

What you need to do is to put your submitting code in the `loadInBackground()` method and you're home.

Comment: But what if I want to do 2 submit operations?

Comment: If you want to do them in the same time, you just put two submits in `loadInBackground()`. If you want to make another submit after one has finished, you call restartLoader() instead of initLoader(): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html#restarting.